# Kali Linux Python IDLE (py-2.7.10) "Cannot find any package '2.7.10' error

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am a beginner to Linux ,However I tried to install python 2.7.10 on Kali Linux 
Problem :
Unable to install IDLE
My Procedure
after Extraction from the downloaded tar ball of Python
.\configure
make
make install

After this I have python 2.7.10 on my terminal when i type Python

For IDLE i tried
sudo apt-get install idle-python 2.7.10
sudo apt-get install idle
All above returns with "Unable to locate python-IDLE"

If you feel it's a duplicate quest Please redirect me to the solution.

Comment: kali I am sure like backtrack is not designed to have everyday packages installed adding to your sources list can also:  *Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.*  so

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are pointing to the right sources ?

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Be sure the following lines are in it :

```
   deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then, run `sudo apt-get update` and you should be able to install idle with `sudo apt-get install idle`

Comment: I have had a look at my sources.list file which seems to have the above contents but still I am getting "Package IDLE has no installation candidate.

Comment: There should only be two lines  in a clean install of kali http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories